# HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. Why?

Tags: php, forms, http, iis, post

```
<form name="enquiry" action="eq.php" method="POST">
                <table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">Name</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" class="enquiry_width" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">E - Mail</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" class="enquiry_width"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">Mobile</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="contactno" class="enquiry_width"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">Address</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" class="enquiry_width"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">Feed Back</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="feedback" class="enquiry_width"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="contact_text">Message</span></td>
                    <td><textarea name="comments" cols="21" rows="5" class="enquiry_width" style="height:50px;"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 <table width="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:10px 0 0 185px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validations()" class="sumbit" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
```

the code works perfectly but showing error code while submitting the form. eq.php file is not executed. Instead it is showing this error. "HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed." why?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are not allowed to make a POST request on that URL. Try checking OPTIONS to see what is allowed.

Edit:

More on HTTP 405 at this link: [HTTP405](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html).

Answer (score -3):

To fix this problem use `www` after the `http://`. For example,
if you are using the link like `http://example.com` then
use it in this format `http://www.example.com`.